# Subviews of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an UITableView with five costum UITableViewCells.
If the TableView scrolls all Cells should perform the same method.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(self.newsViewTable == scrollView) {
        for(int i = 1; i < [self.newsViewTable.subviews count]; i++) {
            [[self.newsViewTable.subviews objectAtIndex:i] hideSocialMediaBar];
        }
    }
}
```

But if I scoll there comes an error!

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView hideSocialMediaBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a9ea90'
```

I don't now why the error deals with an UIImageView?
There is just one direct subview of the UITableView and this is the Cell! 
What is wrong? Why it is an UIImageView?

Comment: where is hideSocialMediaBar method..? with wich condition you want to fine this method ?

Comment: It is solved! :) Thank you nevertheless! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.newsViewTable.subviews` returns an array of subviews. The error is showing up because when it gets to the UIImageView which is in the array of subviews, you're calling the `hideSocialMediaBar` method on it, and it does not respond to that method.

If `hideSocialMediaBar` is something you want to do to your cells you need to call it on a cell.

In your scroll view method, calling `[self.tableview visiblecells]` will return an NSArray of cells visible in the receiver.

So change:

`[[self.newsViewTable.subviews objectAtIndex:i] hideSocialMediaBar];`

to

`[[self.newsViewTable.visiblecells objectAtIndex:i] hideSocialMediaBar];`

Comment: I thougt, that this could it be, but a UIImageView is anywhere!
So, how how do I change the .row of a NSIndexPath?

Comment: Im confused as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish. When someone scrolls you want to `hideSocialMediaBar`? On every cell? Is it supposed to come back when they stop scrolling?

Comment: No! There is a button in the cell which calls showSocialMediaBar!
But this is called in the cell specific class so I don't know in which cell it is called, so I wanna hide in all cells! When it stopps it stays hidden till the button is touched!

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean, but I edited my answer.

Comment: If I scroll the socialMediaBar should be hidden, if I touch the button it should be visible! :D

So this works better! There comes a new Error, but I think I can handle this! :) Thank you! :)